# How can I open a .txt file with excel and execute a macro at the .txt file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have designed a macro and saved it as a .bas file.
Since this macro is designed for a .txt file, I am willing to design a button and assigned this button to open the txt file and execute my macro (.bas).
So far I know how to assign the button to open the txt file but I need a hint to execute my macro (.bas).

Comment: The macro needs to be in the Excel file where you want to run it. You cannot run a macro that is in a `.bas` file. These files are just to export/import macros easily. So you need to import the `.bas` file before you can run the macro in it. `.bas` files cannot be executed directly. • Please [edit] your question and tell us what you are actually trying to do and what the purpose of all this is. I think you are totally up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a .bas file from Excel like this I believe but the permissions required would be to allow interacting with the VBProject and in general, this is not advisable as malicious code could be added and run. But if it is for your own consumption and nobody else etc. I guess it could be done. I would advise changing that permission back after doing it.

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import  "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\example.bas"
Application.Run "Macro Name"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

The alternative (simpler option) is to just import or copy-paste the macro code into Excel and have it as a macro in there with a button in there.

You can also use VBScript to run similar code without Excel etc. (i.e. convert your VBA code to VBScript) and run it stand-alone. But this requires learning the subtle differences between VBA and VBScript.